# Independent Sum Probability question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a question that I dont really know where to begin on any part. I have some ideas, but I am not sure about parts a-c. I think I should get d and e.

Consider independent trials, each of which results in outcome i,i = 0,1,...,k, with probability $p_i,\Sigma^{k}_{i=0}p_i=1$. Let $N$ denote the number of trials needed to obtain an outcome that is not equal to $0$, and let $X$ be that outcome.

(a) Find $P({N=n)},n\ge 1$.

(b) Find $P{(X = j}),j = 1,...,k$. I know they should all be the same.

(c) Show that $P({N = n,X = j)} = P{(N = n)}P{(X = j)}$. Here I am showing independence I know that much

(d) Is it intuitive that N is independent of X?

(e) Is it intuitive that X is independent of N?

Answer (score 1):

***Partial answers only.*** Clues for (a)-(c) as requested.

(a) Geometric. Non-zero is a Success. $P(Success) = 1 - p_0.$

(b) Result must be a number 1 through k. Probabilities should be
proportional to the $p_i$ but need to sum to 1.
So $P(X = j) = p_j/(1 - p_0)$. They would be the same if the original
distribution on $\{1, ..., k\}$ had all $p_i = 1/(k+1),$ for $i = 1,\dots,k$.
(Value of $p_0$ could be different from the rest.)_

(c) $P(N = n, X = j) = P(N=n)P(X=j|N=n),$ but the value of $X$
[as in (b)] doesn't depend on the stopping time.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: so P(X|N)=P(X).